# Problem with error logs in JBoss server logs

Tags: logging, server, jboss

We have a JBoss server with many applications. One of the application is having trouble with the database so it is logging ERROR logs every day in the server log.

The problem is that, it writing logs in a very odd way where every line of the log has the log level "ERROR" instead of one ERROR log and the other logs following it[1].

This is making it hard for us to configure alerts to the server logs.

[1]

```
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19) java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/jdbc/masonds
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at com.org.mason.GlobalMethod.GetDatabaseConnection(GlobalMethod.java:21)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at com.org.mason.dao.MasonWebPage.getRecords(MasonWebPage.java:65)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at com.org.mason.dao.MasonWebPage.<init>(MasonWebPage.java:33)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor583.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:102)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:271)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:169)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:287)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:329)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:193)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:865)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2019-10-27 03:59:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-19)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
```

Linux RHEAL server running Jboss 7.1

Comment: This is a very standard log file format - what issues are you having with it?

Comment: This is just 1 error with the stack trace. But in this log, for some reason, it is writing "ERROR" in every line of the stack trace.

Comment: How is your logging setup (i.e. log4j, slf4j, JBoss)?  I see that it's logging to `stderr` and not a "regular" logger.  How are you calling the logging?

Comment: As @stdunbar stated this is something writing to `stderr` are you doing something like `Throwable.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: @stdunbar. Thank you for the reply. We use log4j for the logging. I am not sure if "Throwable.printStackTrace()" thats something we are doing. But only few ERROR logs are in this format and they are very rarely seen.